# Object At Index of Array with Value For Key

Tags: json, swift

Does anyone know how to get the object at the index of an array, at the value for a specific key, and set it to a string?

I used to do this in Objective-C, but I can't quite figure out how to do it in Swift:

`NSString *rT = [[self.rA objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Value"];`

I've tried different things like this, but they don't work:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
   print("JSON: \(JSON)")
   var name: String? = self.rA[0].valueForKey("item_1") as? String
}
```

Endpoint:

```
[
    {
        "item_1": "Austin",
        "item_2": "Texas"
    }
]
```

Logging:

```
2016-04-01 13:35:42.787 A[66185:7391524] Response Array: (
        {
        "item_1" = Austin;
        "item_2" = Texas;
    }
)
```

Comment: @matt will do, but to clarify, for actual input are you talking about the url, and for desired output are you talking about the json response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have something like array of dictionaries, So I made some test here it is sample code :

**UPDATE**

```
let jsonString = "[ { \"item_1\": \"Austin\", \"item_2\": \"Texas\" }, { \"item_3\": \"Austin3\", \"item_4\": \"Texas4\" } ]"
var array = []
do {
    array = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:.AllowFragments) as! NSArray
} catch {
    print(error)
}

if let unwrappedValue = (array[0]["item_1"]){
    print(unwrappedValue)
}
```

It will return an optional so it would be nice to use `if let` statement to unwrap value

For your usage this code should be like this :

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
    if let unwrappedValue = (JSON[0]["item_1"]){
        print(unwrappedValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: The endpoint JSON response is always just one array, with two dictionary items, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, if completely sure about that endpoint will always return the array with an n-elements dictionary. And you know `key` values, my solution should work. Try it and let me know, if it works

Comment: updated my code too, where does the JSON part fit in your answer?

Comment: `(JSON[0]["key1"])` it means you access first element of JSON array and you'll get value for key = "key1".
it is equivalent to 
`[[JSON objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"key1"];`

Comment: Does `(JSON[0]["key1"])` in place of `["key1":"das"]`?

Comment: I don't think it does, but when I try it there, or in place of `(array[0]["key1"])` I'm still not getting it to work?  Do you mind updating your code real quick? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sure could you provide me an example of this JSON you've receiving?

Comment: No problem, just added, let me know if that does/doesn't make sense

Comment: Take a look at my answer now, in jsonString I place the same JSON that you received from the endpoint. 

If `if let JSON = response.result.value ` gives you an array you don't have to convert String into Array object using :

`array = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:.AllowFragments) as! NSArray`

Comment: Ahh.  So do I need to replace `\"Austin\"` with something so that I can receive whatever that is back from the JSON? I'll get a different city and state each time I hit the endpoint

Comment: And is there any reason you do `, { \"item_3\": \"Austin3\", \"item_4\": \"Texas4\" }` since I don't ever get an `item_3` or `item_4` back from the JSON, its just `item_1` and `item_2`?

Comment: Actually I guess I'm not following you.  `if let JSON = response.result.value ` is where I know that I get a response, and `JSON` becomes that response.  Then I need to use `JSON` to get the string for the value at `item_1` ya know?

Comment: (`JSON` is also serialized I believe because I'm using AlamoFire library)

Comment: If you use Alamofire properly `response.result.value` should be an array. Take a look on my answer I've edited it right now for your usage.

Comment: Thanks thats perfect!